# Using tkinter to create a grid using words from an external file

Tags: python, file, random, tkinter

Okay, this code can display the grid fine, but the way it is programmed is extremely inefficient and I know there is a quicker way of doing this but I can't seem to get it.

Also, in order for this grid to be random I need the words to be randomly allocated rather than always being in the same place. I'm trying to add it to a list and then use 'random.shuffle', but once I've done that I can't extract the words from the list and then put them into the grid.

I've stripped the program down to only the parts which I can get working. Another part of the program makes the grid switch to the same words but in different, random positions.

```
import random

from tkinter import *

root=Tk()

word_list=[]

with open("easy_words.txt", "r") as f:

    word_1=f.read(6)
    word_2=f.read(6)
    word_3=f.read(6)
    word_4=f.read(6)
    word_5=f.read(6)
    word_6=f.read(6)
    word_7=f.read(6)
    word_8=f.read(6)
    word_9=f.read(6)

def easy_grid():

    w=Label(root, text=(word_1), fg='black').grid(row=1, column=1)
    w=Label(root, text=(word_2), fg='black').grid(row=1, column=2)
    w=Label(root, text=(word_3), fg='black').grid(row=1, column=3)
    w=Label(root, text=(word_4), fg='black').grid(row=2, column=1)
    w=Label(root, text=(word_5), fg='black').grid(row=2, column=2)
    w=Label(root, text=(word_6), fg='black').grid(row=2, column=3)
    w=Label(root, text=(word_7), fg='black').grid(row=3, column=1)
    w=Label(root, text=(word_8), fg='black').grid(row=3, column=2)
    w=Label(root, text=(word_9), fg='black').grid(row=3, column=3)

def menu():

    b=Button(root,text='Easy', command=easy_grid()).grid(row=4, column=1)
    b=Button(root,text='Hard', command=print('Hard game')).grid(row=4, column=3)
    b=Button(root, text='Close', command=root.destroy).grid(row=4, column=2)


menu()
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest the following improvements and fixes:

- store the words in the file with some separator, e.g. a space or a comma. Then do `words = f.read().split(" ")` to get all the words as a list
- if you want to randomize that list, use `random.shuffle(words)`
- use two nested loops (or a single loop and some math) to populate the grid
- `b=Button(...).grid(...)` assigns the result of `grid` to `b`, not the button; same for the Labels.
- `command=easy_grid()` will execute the function once and bind the result (`None` again) to the button, not the function itself. Use `command=easy_grid` instead (no `()`)
- you need to call `root.mainloop()` to show the frame

Something like this:

```
def easy_grid():
    with open("easy_words.txt", "r") as f:
        easy_words = f.read().split()
    random.shuffle(easy_words)
    for i, w in enumerate(easy_words):
        Label(root, text=w, fg='black').grid(row=i//3, column=i%3)

def menu():
    Button(root,text='Easy', command=easy_grid).grid(row=4, column=0)
    Button(root, text='Close', command=root.destroy).grid(row=4, column=1)
    Button(root,text='Hard', command=lambda:print('Hard game')).grid(row=4, column=2)

root = Tk()
menu()
root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

There is an easier way to read from your file: use a loop!

```
word_list=[]
with open("easy_words.txt", "r") as f:
    for line in f:
        word_list.append(line)
```

This reads each line in the file and adds them to the end of your list. Which you can later shuffle.

Your easy grid method can also be improved with loops:

```
def easy_grid():
    for i in range(9):
        w=Label(root, text=(word_list[i]), fg='black').grid(row=(i%3)+1, column=(i/3)+1)
```

Which repeats the operation 9 times (given by `range(9)`). Using the variable `i` to figure out which row/column to go in (modulo for row, divide for column)

If you want it to be random, just apply the shuffle to word_list before calling `easy_grid`